# C stack smashing detected

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow

I have a function that counts how many times a words appears on a file. Now for some reason it gets stack smashing detected error, and i dont see the error.

Here is the code:

```
int contar_palabra(const char *nombre_file, const char *palabra){

/*variables locales*/
FILE *file; 
char buffer[50]; 
int bytes_leidos, contador = 0, comparar, cerrar, i;    

/*Abrimos el archivo para lectura*/
file = fopen(nombre_file, "r");

/*Verificamos que se haya abierto correctamente*/
if (file == NULL){
  printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo \n");
  perror(nombre_file);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*Procedemos a contar cuantas veces aparece una palabra*/
while (!feof(file)){

  bytes_leidos = fscanf(file, "%s", buffer);

  if (bytes_leidos > 0){

    /*Hacemos la comparacion*/
    comparar = strcmp(buffer, palabra);
    if (comparar == 0)
      contador++;
  }
  else if(errno == EOF)     
        printf("Error al leer alguna palabra de %s \n", nombre_file);
  else if (bytes_leidos == EOF)
    break;
}

cerrar = fclose(file);

if(cerrar == EOF){
  printf("Error: no se pudo cerra el archivo.");
}

printf("antes de retornar contador \n");
return contador;
```

}

I used valgrind trying to identify the error, and the log file gave me this:

```
  ==2252== Memcheck, a memory error detector
  ==2252== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
  ==2252== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
  ==2252== Command: ./pargrep viejo.txt
  ==2252== Parent PID: 1756
  ==2252== 
  ==2252== 
  ==2252== HEAP SUMMARY:
  ==2252==     in use at exit: 55 bytes in 1 blocks
  ==2252==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 1,389 bytes allocated
  ==2252== 
  ==2252== 55 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
  ==2252==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
  ==2252==    by 0x40B878B: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:138)
  ==2252==    by 0x413D09F: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:32)
  ==2252==    by 0x413D049: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:29)
  ==2252==    by 0x8049142: contar_palabra (in /home/alessandro/OS/Proyecto2/prueba1.0/pargrep)
  ==2252==    by 0x80489D4: main (in /home/alessandro/OS/Proyecto2/prueba1.0/pargrep)
  ==2252== 
  ==2252== LEAK SUMMARY:
  ==2252==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==2252==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==2252==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==2252==    still reachable: 55 bytes in 1 blocks
  ==2252==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  ==2252== 
  ==2252== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
  ==2252== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 8)
```

Whats strange is that it prints a message before returning. 
I really dont see the error, appreciate the help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using plain `%s` as a format specifier to `fscanf` is very dangerous as you have no protection against writing beyond the end of the buffer which is only 50 bytes in your case. Consider providing a width modifier to the format specifier, although this will be handling an accurate count when the width limit is reached more complex.

You may find that reading character by character (`fgetc`) or reading fixed buffers (`fread`) and detecting the word separators by hand yields simpler code.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Thanks!! So i presume that i was reading more than my 50 char, and it gave me a stack overflow. Again thanks!